# SQLAlchemy with Flask does not commit

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

When I submit my form from webpage, I am not able to commit. Flashing data I need, I see they're there and correct, but something fails when committing. I am sure I am making a mistake somewhere because mostly commit are working except two. This is one of the two that is not working.

Models:

```
class Feedback(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'feedback'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    rate = db.Column(db.Integer)
    comment = db.Column(db.Text())
    sender_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    receiver_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Forms:

```
class LeaveFeedbackForm(Form):
    rate =  IntegerField('Rate', validators = [DataRequired(),
                                               NumberRange(min = 1, max = 5, message = 'Rates admitted are only 1,2,3,4,5')])
    comment = TextAreaField('Comment', validators = [DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Views:

```
@app.route('/leave_feedback/<sender>/<receiver>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def leave_feedback(receiver, sender):
    form = LeaveFeedbackForm()
    rec = int(receiver)
    sen = int(sender)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        feedback = Feedback( rate = form.rate.data,
                             comment = form.comment.data,
                             receiver_id = rec,
                             sender_id = sen
                            )
        db.session.add(feedback)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Feedback Left Correctly.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    flash(form.rate.data)
    flash(form.comment.data)
    flash(rec)
    flash(sen)
    return render_template('leave_feedback.html', receiver_id = receiver, sender_id = sender, form = form)
```

html:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <h1>Leave Feedback</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

  <form action="" method="post" name="leavefeedback">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>Rate
                {{ form.rate }}
            </label>
        </div>
       </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>Comment
                {{ form.comment }}
            </label>
        </div>
       </div>


      <div class="row">
          <div class="large-6 columns">
            <input class="button radius" type="submit" value="Leave Feedback">
         </div>
      </div>

  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you show a exception with stacktrace and error message?

Comment: I am not able to stacktrace databases errors on PyCharm. I am new with IntelliJ IDEs, I'm really not able to figure out to set traces I need

Comment: There is no difference what IDE you are using. What "commit fails" means? Do you get "Feedback Left Correctly." ?

Comment: I check my db with DB Browser for Sqlite, and I don't see any new record on table. I think my mistake is on form.validate_on_submit(), because after submit I am not redirect to index and even I don't see flash message

Comment: I had added advice, how you can check form. Also, I would recommend you to use [breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-breakpoints.html) or [debug prints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging#Techniques) in future. It helps you to solve same problems by yourself.

Comment: I found the solution: I simply forgot {{ form.hidden_tag() }} in my html... Never code alone overnight :/
Thank you for support and help!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an `else` statement:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
     ...
else:
    for error in form.errors.itervalues():
        flash(error[0])
```

Then you will get an error message from form.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my mistake, I simply forgot in my form:

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
```